# Is there a way to reduce the amount of loops in this class?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, lambda, refactoring

I have a class where several methods loop over the *list of products*.

I am wondering if there would be a way to reduce the amount of loops as they only do one check really?

Some sort of way to implement a *function* and pass a *predicate*? I discovered **Lambdas** yesterday, but not sure if it would be applicable here.

```java
public class Stock {
    private ArrayList<Products> _productList;
    public Stock(){}

    public Boolean addProduct(Products product){
        return _productList.contains(product) && _productList.add(product);
    }

    public int obtainPos(int code){
        for(int i=0; i < _productList.size(); i++)
            if(_productList.get(i).getCode() == code)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public void removeProduct(int code){
        int pos = obtainPos(code);
        if(pos >=0)
            _productList.remove(pos);
        else
            System.out.println("Error - Product not found.");
    }

    public int productAmount(){ return _productList.size(); }

    public int amountType(String type){
        int i = 0;
        for(Products pr : _productList)
            if(pr.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(type))
                i++;
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Products pr : _productList)
            sb.append(pr.getName()).append(" \n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void itemsToRemove(String reason){
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        for(Products pr : _productList)
            st.append(pr.getName()).append(" - ").append(pr.withdraw(reason)).append("\n");

        System.out.println(st.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Foreach loops are concise and clear, so I wouldn't change them.

Comment: *"I discovered Lambdas yesterday, but not sure it would be applicable here."* - Well yes ... so the next thing you should do is to try to use lambdas to solve this problem yourself.  I think they are unlikely to give a significant improvement in this case ... but by trying to do it yourself you will 1) learn practical knowledge about using streams and lambdas, and 2) start to develop some insight into their advantages / limitations, and when / where it is a good idea to use them.  (Just because you learned a new technique doesn't mean you should apply it to *all* problems.)

Comment: Note: your goal should not be to reduce the number of loops.  It should be "to make the code more readable" or "to improve performance" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a way to reduce the amount of loops

> Some sort of way to implement a function and pass predicate? I
> discovered Lambdas yesterday, but not sure it would be applicable
> here.

If you're considering usage of *lambdas* as a possible option, you can make this code much more concise.

It requires only *very basic knowledge* on the topic of **Java 8** *lambda expressions* and *streams*. As a first step, I suggest you to get familiar with this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Let's refactor these methods one by one.

- `removeProduct()`

You can substitute all the code inside the methods `removeProduct()` and `obtainPos()` with a ***single line*** by using method [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) of the `Collection` interface, like that:

```
products.removeIf(product -> product.getCode() == code);
```

Method `removeIf()` expects a `Predicate` (*a function that produces a boolean value*), and it'll remove every element that matches the given predicate.

This method returns `true` if collection was modified and `false` othewise.

---

- `getAmountByType()`

This method could be implemented by using a tiny stream containing only two operations: `filter()` and `count()`.

In order to create a stream with a *list of products* as a source, you have to invoke method `stream()` on the list.

Method `filter()` is an intermediate operation (*operation that produces a new stream*). As well as `removeIf()` it expects a *predicate*, by conversely to `removeIf()` it will preserve in the resulting stream only elements that match the given predicate.

And method `count()` is terminal operation (*operation that closes the stream and returns a value or does a final action, like* `forEach`) that return the number of element in the stream as `long`.

---

- `toString()`

This method also boils down to a *stream* that consists of two operations: `map()` and `collect()`.

Method `map()` is an *intermediate* operation. It expects a `Function` (*a function that takes an object and produces another object, usually of a different type*). We can implement the function that extracts the name from a product either by using a lambda expression (*as shown in the code below*), or with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Product::getName`.

So in this case, `map()` will transform a stream of products `Stream<Product>` into a stream of product names `Stream<String>`.

Method `count()` is *terminal* operation, that expects a `Collector` (*a special object that populates a mutable container with elements of the stream and produces a result of the execution of the stream pipeline*).

Here we can use a built-in collector `Collectors.joining()` which is designed to join `String` elements into a single string.

---

- `addProduct()`

Although this method is capable of adding new products, there's a logical flow in it:

1. It will return `true` if the list of products already contains the given product, and `false` for a **new** product (*that's a bit counterintuitive*).
2. It will *always add* the given product to the list, regardless whether it's a duplicate or not. Because of that, the process of checking if the given product already exists in the list becomes pointless.

To fix it, the method could be reimplemented in *two ways*:

- allow duplicates and add every given product;
- discard duplicated products.

In both cases implementation is a single statement:

```
return products.add(product);
```

But in order to reject duplicates, you need to make the underlying collection to be a `HashSet` (*note that this change will **not affect** anyhow the rest code listed here*). Assuming that `hashCode/equals` contract was correctly implemented in `Product` class, method `add` will return `false` in case of a duplicate, and `true` if a set was modified (i.e. the product was successfully added).

```
public class ProductInStock {
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>(); // if you change it to List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>(); nothing will break

    public boolean addProduct(Product product) {
        return products.add(product);
    }

    public boolean removeProduct(int code){
        return products.removeIf(product -> product.getCode() == code);
    }

    public int productAmount(){
        return products.size();
    }

    public int getAmountByType(String type) {
        return (int) products.stream()
                .filter(product -> product.getType().equals(type))
                .count();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return products.stream()
                .map(product -> product.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

`main()` - a small demo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProductInStock productInStock = new ProductInStock();

    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Milk", 11, "dairyProducts"));
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Milk", 11, "dairyProducts")); // duplicate
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Milk", 11, "dairyProducts")); // duplicate
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Cottage cheese", 12, "dairyProducts"));
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Cream cheese", 13, "dairyProducts"));
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Bread", 21, "bakedProducts"));
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Muffin", 22, "bakedProducts"));
    productInStock.addProduct(new Product("Cookies", 23, "bakedProducts"));

    System.out.println("Amount by type");
    System.out.println("Baked Products:\t" + productInStock.getAmountByType("bakedProducts"));
    System.out.println("Dairy Products:\t" + productInStock.getAmountByType("dairyProducts"));

    productInStock.removeProduct(12);
    productInStock.removeProduct(21);

    System.out.println("\nProduct Stock after removal:\n" + productInStock);
}
```

**Output**

```
Amount by type
Baked Products: 3
Dairy Products: 3

Product Stock after removal:
Muffin
Cookies
Milk
Cream cheese
```

---

**Sidenotes:**

- Usage of underscore `_` if front of the variable names in Java isn't aligned with the *naming conventions*. In cases when it's necessary to distinguish between a parameter and a field that share the same name, we have the key word `this`.
- It'll be more convenient to make the *product type* to be represented by an `enum` instead of relying on string values.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like an if statement inside your desired single loop that decides between the actions you'd like to take, for example:

```
public void loopClass(int decision) {
for(Products pr : _productList) {
if (decision == choice1) {
//do something
}

if (decision == choice2) {
//do something else
}

//etc etc
}

}
```

Looking at your code I don't see anything wrong with the way you have loops set up though. It seems pretty concise and clear the way you have it set up now. **I would recommend leaving it as is.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashMap<Integer,Products>` instead of an `ArrayList<Products>`.  That would allow you to eliminate `obtainPos` and reduce `addProduct` and `removeProduct` to O(1) operations.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing this for a project, so even though it is a very nice suggestion (I will have it in mind for the future). I am forced to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention lambdas, yes in combination with `Stream` or `List.removeIf` they help. Unfortunately they are an advanced feature, probably treated a bit later.
To show what it would do to i.a. your for-loops:

```
public class Stock {
    private final List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(List<Product> productList) {
        this.productList.addAll(productList);
    }

    public boolean addProduct(Product product) {
        return productList.contains(product) || productList.add(product);
    }

    //public int obtainPos(int code){
    public Optional<Product> obtainByCode(int code) {
        productList.stream()
                .filter(pr -> pr.getCode() == code)
                .findAny();
    }

    public void removeProduct(int code) {
        obtainByCode(code).ifPresentOrElse(pr -> productList.remove(pr),
                () -> System.out.println("Error - Product not found."));
    }

    public int productAmount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public int amountType(String type) {
        return (int) productList.stream()
                .filter(pr -> pr.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(type))
                .count();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return productList.stream()
                .map(Product::getName)
                .map(nm -> nm + " \n")
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    //    return productList.stream()
    //            .map(Product::getName)
    //            .collect(Collectors.joining(" \n"); // At the end without \n.
    }

    public void itemsToRemove(String reason) {
        String items = productList.stream()
                .map(Product::getName)
                .map(nm -> String.format("%s - %s\n", nm, reason))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" \n");
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

Remarks:

- I assumed that the name `Products` should have been `Product`.
- `addProduct` used an AND (THEN) `&&` where I think you meant OR (ELSE) `||`. When the product already exists the added product is discarded. Not sure whether that is desired. A `Product.equals` (on code?) must exist.
- `obtainPos` introduces an internal dynamic feature (when `removeProduct` is called). Better return `Optional<Product>` which is a type-safe wrapper; see `ifPresent`.
- Prefixes like that underscore are not usance in java. You can disambiguate with same named parameters with `this.field`.
- Unchanged (=unreplaced) fields can be `final`.
- It is more expressive to program against interfaces (`List`) instead of the implementing class (`ArrayList`).
- There are primitive types like `int, boolean, char, long`. And there are wrapper classes `Integer, Boolean, Character, Long`. Use the primitive types as more logical. Only for generic parameter types this cannot be done: `List<Integer>`.
- A lambda is either `pr -> pr.getName()` or a method reference `Product::getName`.

Already mentioned is that `Map<Integer, Product> productsByCode = new HashMap<>();` would prove a fast access of a Product by code.

The `for` loops you have are all quite different, so much gain is implausible. However a Stream isolates conditions and such, and might be more flexible.